# Sql Server Shift Report with 4 shift

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

I've got SQL Table that has data for electricity consumption.
Existing columns: Date, Name and Value. Here is a sample:

```
    DT                      Tag                           Value

2018-09-13 17:09:32.553 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 18:09:32.557 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 19:09:32.567 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 20:09:32.580 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 21:09:32.583 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 22:09:32.593 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-13 23:09:32.597 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 00:09:32.603 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 01:09:32.603 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 02:09:32.603 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 03:09:32.610 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 04:09:32.627 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 05:09:32.640 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 06:09:32.643 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 07:09:32.650 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 08:09:32.663 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 09:09:32.677 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 10:09:32.677 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 11:09:32.677 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
2018-09-14 12:09:32.680 Siemens.MDBPLC.elDCS2.elDCS2p   30559.01953125
```

Values are being inserted into the table every hour.

I need to create Shift Reports where we can see which shift consumed energy by average value for hours in shift.
We have 4 shift:

```
2019-09-13 07:00-19:00 A
2019-09-13 19:00-07:00 B
 2019-09-14 07:00-19:00 C
2019-09-14 19:00-07:00 D
```

As a result I need an output like this:

```
Date               Shift  Value
2019-09-13 07:00     A     30559.01953125
2019-09-13 19:00     B     30559.01953125
2019-09-14 07:00     C     30559.01953125
```

They using MS SQL 2012. Can't change structure or anything, only can select data from DB.

Comment: Please provide **sample data**, and **expected result**. You will get much faster and more accurate answers when you do this

Comment: You only seem to have 2 12 hour shifts per day. Why do you call this "4 shifts"?

Comment: Because in our factory we have 4 shifts for 2 days - A B C D, that's why Shift report should cover all 4 shifts

Comment: In your output, is Value the MIN, MAX, or AVG of all of the hourly samples per shift?

Comment: How do you decide when to start at 'A'?  Does this matter?

Comment: Stuart Ainsworth, it's average

Comment: Used_By_Already no it doesn't matter, I just need the sequence when B follows A and C follows B etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have opted to form the cycle of 4 shifts using 2 cross apply operators so that the column aliases can be re-used, hopefully making it easier to read.

Using datediff(hour,...) and modulus from a start point of 2018-01-01 07:00 we can figure out which hours are in the first or second shifts and then the second modulus calculation tells us which of the 2 days is relevant, together we can then make the 4 shift cycles that span 2 days.

```
select
     ca2.shift_start
   , ca2.shift
   , avg(value) avg_value
from table1
cross apply (
    select
           datediff(hour,'20180101 07:00', dt) % 24 hr
        , (datediff(hour,'20180101 07:00', dt) / 24) % 2 dy
    ) ca1
cross apply (
   select case
          when ca1.dy = 0 and ca1.hr between 0  and 11 then 'a'
          when ca1.dy = 0 and ca1.hr between 12 and 23 then 'b'
          when ca1.dy = 1 and ca1.hr between 0  and 11 then 'c'
          when ca1.dy = 1 and ca1.hr between 12 and 23 then 'd'
          end as shift
        , convert(varchar(13),dateadd(hour,-(case when hr < 12 then hr else hr-12 end),dt),121) shift_start
    ) ca2
group by
     ca2.shift_start
   , ca2.shift
order by
     ca2.shift_start
   , ca2.shift


+----+---------------+-------+----------------+
|    |  shift_start  | shift |   avg_value    |
+----+---------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | 2018-09-13 07 | c     | 30559,01953125 |
|  2 | 2018-09-13 19 | d     | 30559,01953125 |
|  3 | 2018-09-14 07 | a     | 30559,01953125 |
+----+---------------+-------+----------------+
```

see: http://rextester.com/VHQK56298

Answer (score 0):

do you have a table that defines the shift ? Here i assumed you have one and the date range defined in shift matches with your sample data (year 2018)

```
;with  
shift_table as
(
    select shift_start = '2018-09-13 07:00', shift_end = '2018-09-13 19:00', shift = 'A'    union all
    select shift_start = '2018-09-13 19:00', shift_end = '2018-09-14 07:00', shift = 'B'    union all
    select shift_start = '2018-09-14 07:00', shift_end = '2018-09-14 19:00', shift = 'C'    union all
    select shift_start = '2018-09-14 19:00', shift_end = '2018-09-15 07:00', shift = 'D'
)
SELECT  s.shift_start, s.shift, Value = avg(t.Value)
FROM    sample_table t
        inner join shift_table s    on  t.DT    >= s.shift_start
                                   and  t.DT    <  s.shift_end
group by s.shift_start, s.shift
```

Comment: I don't have table shift. Can I autogenerate this table in SQL?

Comment: yes. you can. In my query, i am using a `cte` to define the shift data. You can do it simply using the desired date